# After assignment by *pointer the neighbor piece of memory gets filled with ZERO. Why?

Tags: c

I'm learning C with an old book "The C Programming Language" and experimenting with pointers at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main (void)
{
    // init string
    char s[8] = "ZZZZZZZ";
    // it goes: Z Z Z Z Z Z Z \0

    long *p;         // make pointer refering to the same adress as s
    p = s;           // but declared long for modifying 4 bytes at once
    *p = 0x41414141; // and assign hexadecimal constant equal to 65 65 65 65

    // expect output to be: AAAAZZZ
    printf ("%s\n", s);
    // but get the next: AAAA

    // wrote the following line to find out what's wrong with last 4 chars
    printf ("%i%i%i%i\n", s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7]);
    // and those appear to become zero after messing with first 4 ones

    return 0;
}
```

So, the output is:

```
AAAA
0000
```

Why are the last 4 bytes zeroes?

P.S. already got the answer: type long is 8 bytes on x64 machine, and I am inobservant. Surprised what a good thing is StackOverflow. Thank you guys.

Comment: Add `printf("sizeof(long) = %zd\n", sizeof(long));` somewhere in your program and run it again.  What does this print?  (I bet you it prints "sizeof(long) = 8".)

Comment: You should be aware that, because you are learning from an old book, you are writing code which is now considered both incorrect and bad style.

Comment: Oops.. the book is really old, and sizeof long is now also implementation dependent and varies among 32 and 64 bits since modern CPUs have extended 64 architecture. Have I got it right?

Comment: `sizeof(long)` has _always_ been implementation dependent, but yes, that is the issue, I think.

Comment: If `long` is implemented as a 64 bit type, what you get is expected. On a 32 bit system you should get `ZZZZ`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I guess it's better to firstly read an old book which is the best one for understanding, new ones have indexing screwed up and overloaded with info and other authors are not so good at explanation as creators of the language.

Comment: so I need to write some #if #define to force the code give the same result on either 32 or 64 machine?

Comment: `s` also needs to be declared as either `s[9]`, or `s[]` to allow for the trailing `NUL`

Comment: if it was [7] I'd get segmentationfault-coredumped

Comment: @Polazhinets.A see answer below. You don't write code like that, it's wrong.

Comment: got it, thanx. Really amazed to get all these tips in such a short period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `long` is likely 64-bit large. It could work with a `int32_t` pointer (does on my PC):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int
main (void)
{
    // init string
    char s[8] = "ZZZZZZZ";
    // it goes: Z Z Z Z Z Z Z \0

    int32_t *p;         // making pointer refering to the same adress as s
    p = (int32_t*)s;           // but declared as long for modifying 4 bytes at once
    *p = 0x41414141; // and assign hexadecimal constant equal to 65 65 65 65

    // expect output to be: AAAAZZZ
    printf ("%s\n", s);
    // but get the next: AAAA

    // wrote the following line to find out what's wrong with last 4 chars
    printf ("%i%i%i%i\n", s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7]);
    // and those appear to become zero after messing with first 4 ones

    return 0;
}
```

but strictly speaking, this type-punning is a strict-aliasing violation (which makes your program undefined). `memcpy` or `char`-by-`char` copying from the 32-bit integer, or `unions` (safest in case you decided to start allocating the objects dynamically), should do it reliably:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main (void) 
{
    // init string
    char s[8] = "ZZZZZZZ";
    // it goes: Z Z Z Z Z Z Z \0

    int32_t src = 0x41414141;
    memcpy(s, &src, sizeof(src));

    // expect output to be: AAAAZZZ
    printf ("%s\n", s);
    // but get the next: AAAA

    // wrote the following line to find out what's wrong with last 4 chars
    printf ("%i%i%i%i\n", s[4], s[5], s[6], s[7]);
    // and those appear to become zero after messing with first 4 ones

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: wait a minute.. wasn't long = 0x41414141 supposed to give "\0\0\0\0AAAA" instead of "AAAA\0\0\0\0" ?

Comment: @Polazhinets.A You're on a little-endian architecture. The little end comes first.

Comment: oh.. and now I see it really should be the way it is, for compatible result (younger 32bit peace of it still finds it place right where the pointer points and the following 4 bytes serve as extension to store higher part)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put different values and you will see the architecture is little endian:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
char s[8] = "ZZZZZZZ";
// it goes: Z Z Z Z Z Z Z \0

long *p;
p = (long *)s;
*p = 0x41424344; // A B C D

printf ("%s\n", s);

return 0;
}
```

result: DCBA

and the rest of the result is 0 because you assigned:

```
*p = 0x0000000041424344; // /0 /0 /0 /0 A B C D
```